# How to bring a TreeViewItem in the visible (scroll) area

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm looking for a way to navigate by code to an item in a tree view. The object should be moved into the visible area. I could not find a method in either TTreeView or TTreeViewItem.

The following approach does not work under all circumstances because the item position is not always updated:

```
procedure TfmxMain.MakeItemVisible(Item: TTreeViewItem);
begin
  trvMyTreeView.ViewportPosition :=
    TPointF.Create(min(Item.Position.X - trvSlideGroups.ClientWidth / 2, 0),
     min(Item.Position.Y - trvSlideGroups.ClientHeight / 2, 0));
end;
```

Comment: Selected item or not? You should have a look at Win32 TreeView messages [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tvm-setautoscrollinfo) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tree-view-controls#tree-view-item-position). For example the TVM_SETAUTOSCROLLINFO message?  [EDIT] Sorry I didn't noticed that you were using Firemonkey. Should be a bit more tricky...

Comment: The Item is selected at the time point when `MakeItemVisible` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deep analysis of FMX.TreeView I found a simple solution:

```
procedure TfmxMain.MakeItemVisible(Item: TTreeViewImageItem);
begin
  Item.Deselect;
  Item.Select;
end;
```

This simple manipulation calls the internal method `TCustomTreeView.UpdateSelection`, that moves the selected item to the visible area.